# how does this UITextField work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

Does anyone know on how to create a UITextField that behaves like this:

[image]

My guess is that it's just a UITextField that is put inside a UIToolBar?
Or is it a searchbar used as an input? If anyone knows how to make a multiline
textinput that looks like this, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)?

For the rounded corners, use the text view's layer.

```
[[textView layer] setCornerRadius:15];
```

Comment: I see there's some kind of border in it.. seems like it's inside of something

Comment: CALayer has borderWidth and borderColor properties.

Comment: what would be the closest setup of borderWidth and borderColor to get a similar look like that picture?